# Google Visualization Chart Detached Dom Tree

Tags: backbone.js, google-visualization, marionette

I have a dashboard web app written using Marionette and requirejs. In this app I use the google visualization api to generate my charts.
A while after started development I noticed that I had memory leaks. In Chrome Canary's task manager I can see memory increasing as charts are drawn and removed. I never see a memory decrease, it only goes up.
I took some heap snapshots and saw that I have a lot of detached dom trees, all referring to the svg elements and other of the generated charts.

Now, the rest of my views and subviews are being cleaned up by marionette's inherent methods, and the only things that remain are these chart detached dom elements.

I tried to implement some clean up code in the onClose methods of the views that contain the charts:

- google's clearChart method
- jquery empty() and remove() on the html nodes
- javascript's delete function

None of this seams to help as the detached dom trees keep appearing and the memory keeps increasing.

Has anyone faced this problem?

EDIT

Here's the source code for a chart view

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'dispatchers/event-dispatcher', 'utils/utils', 'utils/chart-utils', 'goog!visualization,1,packages:[corechart], matchMedia'], function($, _, Backbone, eventDispatcher, utils, chartUtils) {
    'use strict';

    var MallKPIChart = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        template: _.template('<div></div>'),

        onShow: function() {

            var self = this;
            self.$el.height(self.$el.width() / 2.5);
            var data = self.options.data;
            var range = self.options.range;
            var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            chartData.addColumn('string', 'date');
            chartData.addColumn('number', 'Visits');
            chartData.addColumn('number', 'Average Visits');

            $.each(data['data'], function(i, object) {

                var row = [utils.timeConverter(parseInt(object['timestamp'], 10) / 1000, range), object['count'], data['average']];
                chartData.addRow(row);
            });

            var titleFontSize, pointSize, lineWidth, fontSize;
            if (window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 1024px)').matches) {

                titleFontSize = 10;
                pointSize = 1;
                lineWidth = 0.8;
                fontSize = 8;
            } else {

                titleFontSize = 15;
                pointSize = 4;
                lineWidth = 2;
                fontSize = 10;
            }

            var options = {

                title: self.options.title,
                titleTextStyle: {

                    color: '#747474',
                    fontName: '"Open Sans"',
                    fontSize: titleFontSize
                },
                fontSize: fontSize,
                chartArea: {
                    'width': '78%',
                    'height': '58%',
                    'left': '12%'
                },
                colors: ['#E87013'],
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                areaOpacity: 0.25,
                animation: {
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'out',
                },
                pointSize: pointSize,
                lineWidth: lineWidth,
                hAxis: {
                    format: 'd/MM/y',
                    textPosition: 'out',
                    baselineColor: '#747474',
                    gridlines: {

                        color: '#efeeed'
                    },
                    textStyle: {

                        color: '#747474'
                    },
                    maxTextLines: 1
                },
                vAxis: {
                    textPosition: 'out',
                    textStyle: {

                        color: '#747474'
                    },
                    baselineColor: '#747474',
                    gridlines: {

                        color: '#efeeed'
                    },
                    maxValue: self.options.max,
                    minValue: 0
                },
                series: {
                    1: {
                        type: 'line',
                        color: '#DE309C',
                        pointSize: 0,
                        lineWidth: lineWidth
                    }
                },
                legend: {

                    position: 'top',
                    alignment: 'end'
                },
                curveType: 'function'
            };

            self.chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(self.$el[0]);
            self.chart.draw(chartData, options);

            return self;
        },

        onClose: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.chart.clearChart();
            self.chart = null;
        },


    });

    return MallKPIChart;

});
```

And a chart instance is initialised and shown in a marionette.layout region like so:

```
self.visitsChart.show(new MallKPIChart({

    title: 'SHOPPING CENTRE VISITS',
    data: self.mallKPI.get('captures'),
    range: self.range
}));
```

And here's a screenshot of the heap snapshot containing svg detached elements (as I keep closing and opening views, the snapshots' size increases)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjv6b.png

Comment: Could you post some example code that demonstrate the leak?  I'd like to take a look and see if I can track down anything specific.

Comment: I've just added the code related to the chart view.

Comment: FYI, the newest release candidate version (load v1.1 instead of v1) includes some fixes for memory leak issues.

Answer (score 0):

The API has had memory leak issues before, so I'm not particularly surprised that you are seeing this.  File a bug report on it [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list), including as much detail as you can, and preferably a code sample that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Isn't there a way to remove these svg,rect,circle elements in a safe way? I tried to remove them manually but they still appear as detached dom elements.

Comment: I don't know why they aren't being garbage collected after being detached, so I don't know what you should do different to make the leak go away.

Comment: Is there a way to find out why they are not being garbage collected?